# I cannot prevent user from editing labels in ListView

Tags: c, windows, listview, sdk

According to msdn, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774798%28VS.85%29.aspx,
returning TRUE prevents user from editing labels.

So I wrote the code below:
Main:

```
WinMain(...)
{
    DialogBox(..., DlgProc)
}
```

DlgProc:

```
DlgProc(...)
{
    switch(message) {
    case WM_NOTIFY:
        if((NMHDR *)lParam->code == LVN_BEGINLABELEDIT) {
            return TRUE;
        return FALSE;
    ...
}
```

Still, the labels can be edited. I dont want to cancel the style LVS_EDITLABELS, because sometimes I would like to allow the users edit labels.

Does anyone know the problem? Thank you.

Comment: Returning `TRUE` from `LVN_BEGINLABELEDIT` does work. There must be something else happening that is interfering.

Comment: Post some more code, the problem is certainly elsewhere. Can you make a really small app that can be posted here which shows the problem?

Comment: Yes I did it, thank you all.
I added a line before returning TRUE.

    SetWindowLongPtr(hwndDlg, DWLP_MSGRESULT, TRUE);

and everything works fine. Microsoft had some dirty work in their architecture, haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Returning TRUE from a DialogProc() doesn't mean what you think it does.  Quoting from the MSDN library article:

> Typically, the dialog box procedure should return TRUE if it processed
>   the message, and FALSE if it did not. If the dialog box procedure
>   returns FALSE, the dialog manager performs the default dialog
>   operation in response to the message.
>
> If the dialog box procedure processes a message that requires a
>   specific return value, the dialog box procedure should set the desired
>   return value by calling SetWindowLong(hwndDlg, DWL_MSGRESULT, lResult)
>   immediately before returning TRUE. Note that you must call
>   SetWindowLong immediately before returning TRUE; doing so earlier may
>   result in the DWL_MSGRESULT value being overwritten by a nested dialog
>   box message.