# Win32 C++ ListView HDN_BEGINTRACK not working

Tags: c, listview, winapi, win32gui

I have a ListView whose columns I'd like to prevent being resized. I'm using code similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13325887/winapi-listview-cant-prevent-columns-from-resizing) question, however my `HDN_BEGINTRACK` message isn't recognised.

My code to create the ListView:

```
HWND Instructions_ListView = CreateWindowEx(LVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER |
      LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT, WC_LISTVIEW, L"", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | 
      LVS_REPORT | LVS_EDITLABELS, 320, 50, 300, 400, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

My code to handle the header events follows. `WM_NOTIFY` is inside of `WndProc` for the main program window:

```
case WM_NOTIFY:
{
    UINT debugval = (((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code);
    switch (((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code)
    {
        case HDN_BEGINTRACKA:
        case HDN_BEGINTRACK:
        {
            ::MessageBox(hWnd, L"RESIZE", L"", MB_OK);
            break;
        }
    }
    break;
}
```

When debugging the value of `debugval` is `4294966969` when breaking on (what should be) the `HDN_BEGINTRACK` event.

Absolutely stumped as to why it's not working as intended; any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ListView's header control is a child of the ListView, so the header's `WM_NOTIFY` notifications will be sent to the ListView itself, not to your parent window.  As such, your WndProc will not see them.

To catch `WM_NOTIFY` (and `WM_COMMAND`) messages sent by the ListView's internal child controls, you need to [subclass the ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/subclassing-overview) using `SetWindowLongPtr(GWL_WNDPROC)` or `SetWindowSubclass()`.

FYI, `HDN_BEGINTRACKA` has a value of `4294966990` (`-306`, hex `0xFFFFFECE`), and `HDN_BEGINTRACKW` has a value of `4294966970` ( `-326`, hex `0xFFFFFEBA`).

You say you are getting a `WM_NOTIFY` notification with a `code` of `4294966969`.  That is `0xFFFFFEB9` (dec `-327`), which is the `HDN_ENDTRACKW` notification.

Comment: Great stuff, seems to be working now. Thanks! Incidentally, why would my main `WndProc()` process `HDN_ENDTRACKW` but not `HDN_BEGINTRACKW` do you know?

Comment: Neither message should be getting sent by the ListView to your main window. Did you check to verify that the `NMHDR::hwndFrom` field of the `HDN_ENDTRACK` notification is the `HWND` of the ListView itself (or its header - you can use `ListView_GetHeader()` to get that `HWND`), and not some other control on your main window?

Comment: The `hwndFrom` value matches the value returned from `ListView_GetHeader()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Actually the listview **does** forward some header notifications to its parent; when you resize a header the listview will forward you `HDN_ITEMCHANGING` and `HDN_ITEMCHANGED` notifications, and will also forward you `HDN_ENDTRACK` when tracking stops. I don't think this is actually documented though.

Answer (score 0):

When using COMCTL32 version 5, applications need to send common controls a CCM_SETVERSION message to take advantage of new functionality and fixes not available in earlier versions. The list view control does not forward all header notifications unless the control version is greater than or equal to 5. The List View control in COMCTL32 version 6 forwards all header notifications without sending the control a CCM_SETVERSION message.

So in your sample after creation of list view please add the below line

> SendMessage(Instructions_ListView, CCM_SETVERSION, 5, 0);